# mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the error is in  `$quant=mysql_result($quantity, 0);`

```
$quantity=("SELECT product_qty_available FROM product WHERE product_id={$_POST['id']} ");
$quant=mysql_result($quantity, 0);


if($quant > $_POST['quant'])
{
  echo "Input Quantity Exceeded!";

}
else
{
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you aren't actually querying your database.

`$quantity=("SELECT product_qty_available FROM product WHERE product_id={$_POST['id']} ");`

should be

`$quantity=mysql_query("SELECT product_qty_available FROM product WHERE product_id={$_POST['id']} ");`

Answer (score 2):

try this >>

---

```
$quantity=mysql_query("SELECT product_qty_available FROM product WHERE product_id={$_POST['id']} ");

$quant = mysql_result($quantity, 0);

if (!$quant) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
    }
if($quant > $_POST['quant'])
{
  echo "Input Quantity Exceeded!";

}
else
{
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $quantity=mysql_query("SELECT product_qty_available FROM product WHERE product_id='"$_POST['id']."'") or die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
   // $quant = mysql_result($quantity);
    if(mysql_num_rows($quantity) > $_POST['quant'])
    {
      echo "Input Quantity Exceeded!";
    }
    else
    {
      exit;
    }
```

try this this will work.